# CS6 Error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Vector3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm trying to use vectors to make an enemy track a target (player's ship). However, I keep getting Error 1046. Any advice? The error occurs on the line containing the drawForceVector function in the Game.as file.

Here is my Game.as file code:

```
    package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Vector3D;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {
        public static var mouse :Vector3D = new Vector3D(100, 100);

        public var boids :Vector.<Boid> = new Vector.<Boid>;
        public var forces :Sprite;

        public function Game() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e :Event) :void {
            var i :int, boid :Boid;

            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                boid = new Boid(stage.stageWidth * Math.random(), stage.stageHeight * Math.random(), 20 +  Math.random() * 20);

                addChild(boid);
                boids.push(boid);
            }

            forces = new Sprite();
            addChild(forces);
        }

        public function update():void {
            var i :int;

            forces.graphics.clear();

            for (i = 0; i < boids.length; i++) { 
                boids[i].update();
                drawForces(boids[i]);
            }
        }

        private function drawForces(boid :Boid) :void {
            var desired  :Vector3D = boid.desired.clone();
            var velocity :Vector3D = boid.velocity.clone();
            var steering :Vector3D = boid.steering.clone();

            velocity.normalize();
            desired.normalize();
            steering.normalize();

            // Force vectors
            drawForceVector(boid, velocity, 0x00FF00);      
            drawForceVector(boid, desired, 0x454545);
            drawForceVector(boid, steering, 0x0000FF);

            // Target
            forces.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x323232);
            forces.graphics.beginFill(0x323232);
            forces.graphics.drawCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 10);
            forces.graphics.endFill();
        }

        private function drawForceVector(boid :Boid, force :Vector3D, color :uint, scale :Number = 100) :void {        //ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
            forces.graphics.moveTo(boid.x + boid.width / 2, boid.y + boid.height / 2);
            forces.graphics.lineStyle(2, color);
            forces.graphics.lineTo(boid.x + force.x * scale, boid.y + force.y * scale);
        }
    }
}
```

Boid.as Code:

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Vector3D;
    import flash.object.Vector3D;

    public class Boid extends MovieClip
    {
        public static const MAX_FORCE       :Number = 0.4;
        public static const MAX_VELOCITY    :Number = 3;

        public var position     :Vector3D;
        public var velocity     :Vector3D;
        public var target       :Vector3D;
        public var desired      :Vector3D;
        public var steering     :Vector3D;
        public var mass         :Number;

        public function Boid(posX :Number, posY :Number, totalMass :Number = 20) {
            position = new Vector3D(posX, posY);
            velocity = new Vector3D(-1, -2);
            target   = new Vector3D(310, 240);
            desired  = new Vector3D(0, 0); 
            steering = new Vector3D(0, 0); 
            mass     = totalMass;

            truncate(velocity, MAX_VELOCITY);

            x = position.x;
            y = position.y;

            graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
            graphics.endFill();
        }

        private function seek(target :Vector3D) :Vector3D {
            var force :Vector3D;

            desired = target.subtract(position);
            desired.normalize();
            desired.scaleBy(MAX_VELOCITY);

            force = desired.subtract(velocity);

            return force;
        }

        public function truncate(vector :Vector3D, max :Number) :void {
            var i :Number;

            i = max / vector.length;
            i = i < 1.0 ? 1.0 : i;

            vector.scaleBy(i);
        }

        public function update():void {
            target = Game.mouse;

            steering = seek(target);

            truncate(steering, MAX_FORCE);
            steering.scaleBy(1 / mass);

            velocity = velocity.add(steering);
            truncate(velocity, MAX_VELOCITY);

            position = position.add(velocity);

            x = position.x;
            y = position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.as Code:

```
    package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;

    [SWF(width = "600", height = "480")]

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var game :Game = new Game();

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
            stage.frameRate = 30;

            addChild(game);
        }

        private function mouseMove(e :MouseEvent) :void {
            Game.mouse.x = e.stageX;
            Game.mouse.y = e.stageY;
        }

        private function enterFrame(e :Event) :void {
            game.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check which class and which line throws that error. It cannot be in the function you've specified because you are using it way before that. And if it wasn't able to include it, it would throw error on another line. Check your target version, despite the fact that Vector3D is pretty old. Just permit debugging and see what's happening in your file..

Comment: @AndreyPopov: Thanks for the quick response. All the above code I've posted is the only code I have. Also, it says in the description that the error occurs in line 67 of Game.as, which happens to be the line containing the aforementioned function.

Comment: Well you've used it way before when declaring mouse. Double check you don't have any special characters (like 'o' in other language). Import the class properly (copy name from somewhere) and replace all instances. Also what's the target version?

Comment: @AndreyPopov: You'll have to excuse me, I'm still new to AS3 and Flash. Could you clarify as to what you mean by target version?

Comment: Depends on the program you build with. If with FlashDevelop - project properties. If with Flash IDE - Publish Settings.

Comment: @AndreyPopov: Ok, I found Publish Settings. Says here it's running on Flash Player 9. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target version of the player must be higher than the one you've got - Flash Player 9. As seen by the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html), it's said that `Vector3D` is included in: *Runtime Versions: Flash Player 10, AIR 1.5*. So basically you are building for so old Flash Player, that it still doesn't have this class inside it.

Simply change the target version to the latest possible one, and be sure it's higher than Flash Player 10. That will do the job! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The good news is that that particular error no longer appears. However, an entirely new slew of errors just arose. I'm actually working on this project with a partner, and it looks like he added some code into the timeline itself in an "Actions" layer. Whatever he put in, there are now Errors 1046 and 1180. These errors weren't around before I changed the target version. Maybe the code I'm using is too outdated to be recognized?

Comment: Welcome to the club of the doomed :) Working with such old code is true madness. I advise you to revise the code and modify what's wrong (again checking each line and importing the proper classes). Also - remove all the code from frames, as this is again a very bad habit. Unfortunately there is no easy solution to your problem, you just need to debug all that crap. Flash Player 9 is released about 2008. You can imagine how old it is and how bad it is to work with it.. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I guess code like ".gotoAndPlay" is considered outdated now? Ah well, I'll figure it out. :)

Comment: `gotoAndPlay` still works properly. You first need to import all the classes needed (1046 error) inside those frames. Then if there are more errors - post new question here, as this one is already answered :) Cheers!